# Escape variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file with a lot of lines like messages:

> 1. valid user
> 2. operation enable
> 3. you don\'t have rights to do this
> 4. please enter more than 5 characters ...

and i use a bash script to read this file like

```
while read line
do
    ....
    echo "${line}"
    ....
done
```

and returns all good, but in the message 3, just return:

> 1. you don't have rights to do this

without the `"\"`

how i can return the exactly line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then try `read -r line` instead.